# Is $T$ necessarily a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$ $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, is T necessarily a linear transformation?

My instinct is no since surely it has to also be additive in order to be linear (by definition), but I can't seem to think of a counterexample.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Say $T(x,y)=0$ unless $y=0$ but that $T(x,0)=x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}$. Clearly $T(\alpha x,\alpha y)=\alpha T(x,y)$ for all $x,y,\alpha\in\mathbb R$, but $T(1,1)=\sqrt[3]2\ne T(0,1)+T(1,0)=2$.

Comment: Not defined for $x,y<0$ but your argument holds also for $x^2$ and simple square root.

Comment: It is defined for all $x,y$, since $x^3$ is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: As far as I know, roots are only well defined for positive numbers, anything else is only by accident. BTW., how can you manage an answer in only  a few seconds? Do you have a neurolink ;-) ?

Comment: I am saying that for each $x\in\mathbb R$, there is a unique $y\in\mathbb R$ such that $x=y^3$, whether $x$ is positive or negative.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: as far as I know, cubic roots are used to be defined for negatives (as are all odd roots). And if you disagree, the function can be explicitly defined so for the sake of this answer. This would *not* work for a square root.

Comment: OK, I give in, ..., the prime idea works for simple, square roots, too, everything else is a a debate about definitions and words.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, define
$$
T(x, 0) = (x, 0)
$$
and
$$
T(x, y) = (0,0) 
$$
for $y \ne 0$. Now consider that $(1, 1) = (0, 1) + (1, 0)$ and apply $T$ to both sides assuming linearity, and arrive at a contradiction.